# Elasticsearch minimum master nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a 3 node cluster with `minimum_master_nodes` set to `2`. If I shut down all nodes **except the master**, leaving one node online, the cluster is no longer operational.

Is this by design? It seems like the node that was the master shouldd remain operational, instead I get errors like this:

```
{"error":"MasterNotDiscoveredException[waited for [30s]]","status":503}
```

All the other settings are stock and I am using the aws cloud plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is intentional.

### Split brain

Imagine a situation where the other 2 nodes were still running but couldn't communicate to the the third  node - you'd end up with two clusters otherwise known as a "split brain".

As the two clusters could be updating and deleting data independently of each other then recovery would be very difficult - you wouldn't have a single source of truth for the data.

By setting `minimum_master_nodes` to `(n/2)+1`  (were n is the number of nodes) you can prevent a split brain.

### Single Node

If you know that the first two nodes have definitely died and not coming back - you can set the `minimum_master_nodes`to 1 on the remaining node (and also set to one on the other nodes before you restart them).

There is also an option [no master block](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html#no-master-block) that lets you control what happens when you don't have a valid cluster - e.g. you could make the remaining node read-only until the cluster is re-established.

Comment: n: number of `master_eligible_nodes`